# Total number of elements from dictionary

Tags: swift, swift4

I have a dictionary of type `[String: Any]` and I cannot get the total number of elements of internal dictionary.

```
struct ICP {
        let staff = [
            "teachers": [
                    [
                        "name": "Teacher One"
                    ],
                    [
                        "name": "Teacher Two"
                    ],
                    [
                        "name": "Teacher Three"
                    ],
                    [
                        "name": "Teacher Four"
                    ]
                ]
        ]  as [String : Any]
    }
```

I need to get the total number of teachers from the above dictionary.

Comment: `staff["teachers"]?.count`

Answer (score 0):

First of all inside `ICP` struct you declared a constant variable named `staff` which contains a dictionary of kind `[String: [[String: String]]]` or shortly `[String: [Any]]`, when you access `teachers` then you have a collection of single dictionaries which is kind of `[[String: String]]`.

I suggest you to create a method inside the `ICP` class and call it `teachersCount`

### Swift 5.1

Like:

```
struct ICP {

    func teachersCount() -> Int {

        guard let teachers = staff["teachers"] as? [[String: String]] else {return 0}

        return teachers.count

   }
```

You can call it outside of struct like:

```
ICP().teachersCount()
```

And Inside your struct like:

```
self.teachersCount()
```